# bootstrap round-circle class elements with border and padding

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap carousel with multiple items.

My html:

```
<div class="carousel w-100 " data-ride="carousel" id="recipeCarousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block col-sm-12 col-md-4 rounded-circle mystyle"  src="{% static 'core/src/img/staff_member_01.jpg'%}">
            <img class="d-block col-sm-12 col-md-4 rounded-circle mystyle" src="{% static 'core/src/img/staff_member_02.jpg'%}">
            <img class="d-block col-sm-12 col-md-4 rounded-circle mystyle"  src="{% static 'core/src/img/staff_member_03.jpg'%}">
        </div>
        [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.mystyle{
 border:1px solid #d3232e;
}
```

As you see in the screenshot below, my issue is that I need to give some padding between the images (handled by bootstrap grid system), and that breaks the border layout.

[image]

If I use margin and delete padding

```
.mystyle{
  margin: 0 0.4em;
  padding: 0!important;
  border:1px solid #d3232e;
}
```

[image]

HELP! :-)

Thank you

**EDIT 1** 
I wrote a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003137/bootstrap-4-carousel-jquery-not-working-as-expected) to solve the issue of the broken carousel jQ after fixing the problem posed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the images inside col divs, and make them responsive using `img-fluid`...

```
<div class="carousel w-100" data-ride="carousel" id="recipeCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner text-center w-100" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item d-flex row active">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid mystyle" src="//placehold.it/300"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid mystyle" src="//placehold.it/300"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid mystyle" src="//placehold.it/300"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then there will be no overlap.

https://www.codeply.com/go/b7DE9Q6AOm

Comment: thank you for your answer! It does not work yet, but the path is set. My problem now is that the <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"> around the <img> breaks the js logic. I edited my question to explain myself better..

Comment: The edited question is very different than the original. I've answered the original. You should isolate the 2nd issue and if you can't resolve it ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Put every image inside a container.

```css
.round-container{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="round-container">
<img class="rounded-circle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" width="100">
</div>

<div class="round-container">
<img class="rounded-circle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" width="100">
</div>

<div class="round-container">
<img class="rounded-circle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" width="100">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it did not work. The reason is that the js got broken and the layout is not responsive..